# Show the induced sequence $A\otimes G \to B\otimes G\to C\otimes G \to 0$ is exact, how do we use the cokernel?

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, exact-sequence

> For a fixed Abelian group $G$, any map $f:A\to B$ induces a
> homomorphism $$f\otimes \operatorname{id}\colon A\otimes G \to
>  B\otimes G.$$
>
> Show that this defines a right exact functor, i.e. for any sequence
> $$A \to B \to C \to 0$$ the induced map $$A\otimes G \to B\otimes G
>  \to C\otimes G \to 0$$ is also exact.

I am currently working through the solution, but I don't understand it. I have several questions. The solution says

> Since the $0$ map induces the $0$ map on tensor products and
> $(f\otimes \operatorname{id})\circ (g\otimes\operatorname{id}) = (f
>  \circ g) \otimes \operatorname{id}$, we see that any two successive
> maps still compose to the trivial map.

Ok, this makes sense but why do i need it in this case? And shouldn't it be $g\circ f$ rather than $f\circ g$ ?

This is where I have most trouble following:

> Also $f\otimes \operatorname{id}$ is clearly surjective if $f$ is.
> Thus it sufices to show that the map $B \otimes
>  G/\operatorname{im}(f\otimes \operatorname{id}) \to C \otimes G$ is an
> isomorphism.

Why is that? Why does it sufice to show that $B \otimes
 G/\operatorname{im}(f\otimes \operatorname{id}) \to C \otimes G$  is an isomorphism to prove exactness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f:A\to B$ is surjective. Then for $b\otimes g\in A\otimes G$, if $f(a)=b$, we have $(f\otimes 1)(a\otimes g)=f(a)\otimes g=b\otimes g$, so $f\otimes 1$ is surjective. That takes care of this part. Now we need the fact that $\mathrm{im}(f\otimes 1)= \mathrm{ker}(g\otimes 1).$

Yes you are right that it should be $g\circ f$ instead of $f\circ g$. You need that $(g\otimes 1)\circ (f\otimes 1)=0$ because this shows that $\mathrm{im}(f\otimes 1)\subset \mathrm{ker}(g\otimes 1)$. Now you need to prove the reverse inclusion in order to complete the proof.

Showing that the induced map $(B\otimes G)/\mathrm{im}(f\otimes G)\to C\otimes G$ is an isomorphism suffices. Indeed, since $g\otimes 1$ is surjective (because $g$ is), we have $C\otimes G\cong (B\otimes G)/\mathrm{ker}(g\otimes 1)$ by the first (?) isomorphism theorem. If $\mathrm{im}(f\otimes 1)$ were a strict subset of $\mathrm{ker}(g\otimes 1)$, then the induced map $$(B\otimes G)/\mathrm{im}(f\otimes G)\to C\otimes G\cong (B\otimes G)/\mathrm{ker}(g\otimes 1)$$ would be a quotient, actually the quotient by $\mathrm{ker}(g\otimes 1)/\mathrm{im}(f\otimes 1)$.

Comment: thank you so much @D.Brogan! This is incredibly helpful. I am working through the details of your answer and will definitely return with 1-2 questions very soon.

Comment: I have two questions. Why do we want $f$ and $f\otimes\operatorname{id}$ to be surjective? If $f$ is surjective, that would imply $g:B\to C$ is the $0$-map, wouldn't it? I don't see how this helps.

And what do you mean by "the induced map would be a quotient"?

Comment: I do understand why $C\otimes G \cong (B\otimes G)/\ker(g\otimes\operatorname{id})$ but i don't see how this implies $ \ker (g\otimes \operatorname{id}) \subset \operatorname{im}(f\otimes \operatorname{id})$.

Comment: This is a theorem: if $f:A\to B$ is surjective, then $f\otimes 1:A\otimes G\to B\otimes G$ is surjective. You apply this theorem to $g$ to get that the sequence is exact at the last term. That may have been a bit confusing. Sorry about that.

Comment: As for your second question, let $K=\mathrm{ker}(g\otimes 1)$ and $I=\mathrm{im}(f\otimes 1).$ Then we already have $I\subset K.$ Now, the induced map $(B\otimes G)/K\to C\otimes G$ is an isomorphism. The induced map $(B\otimes G)/I\to C\otimes G$ is the quotient map, the quotient by $K/I$. If this is an isomorphism, then it must be that $K/I=0,$ so that $K=I,$ which is the desired conclusion.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience. Let me see if i understood it correctly. By the first iso-theorem we know $(B\otimes G)/K \cong C\otimes G$. Now since $I \subset K$, by the 2nd iso-theorem we know that the quotient of $(B\otimes G)/I$ by $K/I$ yields $B\otimes K \cong C\otimes G$. If we can prove that $(B\otimes G)/I \cong C\otimes G$ we have proven that $K/I = 0$. Is that a correct summarization? I am a bit unsure whether my conclusions were correct.

Comment: Yes that's exactly right.

Comment: Thank you so much @D. Brogan. You were incredibly helpful.